# How to print desired observations in one page?

Tags: sas

Suppose if i have *20 observations* in a dataset and i want to print *10 observations in one page* and *10 observations in other page*. Is there any logic to print observations like that?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options.

- `PS` option allows you to control the number of lines per page, in LISTING output.
- `PAGEBY` statement in `PROC PRINT` allows you to specify a variable that a new page is printed for each value of.
- For other PROCs, `BY` will generally produce a new logical page and thus would work similarly to `PAGEBY`

Comment: You would use `BY` in `PROC REPORT`.

Comment: I tried to figure out one solution for my question. If i am doing listing i am able to create flags so that i am able to print desired observations.Suppose i am willing to print 10 obs per page. Then i used below code.

Comment: Sure Joe next time i will make sure of my comments (I will cut all crap). Thanks Joe Cheers..........

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure out one solution for my above problem by creating flags.
suppose if i want to print 10 obs per page then i created below flag
and used this in my proc report.

****Creating flags at desired observation range ;**

```
data page;
set test;
p=ceil(_n_/10);
run;
```

****Implementing the above flag in the following code;**

```
Proc report data=page;
column p x y;
define p/order noprint;
define x/display;
define y/display;
break after p/page;
run;
```

This solves my problem and print only 10 obs per page.